# feed problem in firefox and google

Tags: php, firefox, feed, feedparser

i have problem when creating feed. it's can be read by feedreader, and also shown in firefox but failed in google.

this is my feed header:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
<title>Myfeed</title>
<link>http://www.myfeed.com/</link>
<description>This is myfeedFeed</description>
<lastBuildDate>Mon, 12 agust 2105 11:17:00 GMT</lastBuildDate>
<language>en-us</language>
```

This is my feed outut with 2 items

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="2.0"
    xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
    xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/"
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
    xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
    xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/"
    xmlns:slash="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/" >
<channel>
<title>myfeed Feed</title>
<atom:link href="http://www.localhost.com/" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
<link>http://www.localhost.com/</link>
<description>This is myfeed Feed</description>
<lastBuildDate>Mon, 12 Sep 2015 18:37:00 GMT</lastBuildDate>
<language>en-us</language>
<sy:updatePeriod>weekly</sy:updatePeriod>
<sy:updateFrequency>1</sy:updateFrequency>
<title>Hello Developer</title>
<link>http://localhost.com/</link>
<guid>http://localhost.com/</guid>
<pubDate>20100907</pubDate>
<dc:creator>myfeed</dc:creator>
<category><![CDATA[Developer]]></category>
<category><![CDATA[Tutorial]]></category>
<category><![CDATA[Wordpress]]></category>
<description><![CDATA[Hello developer license]]></description>
<license>Developer</license>

<quantity>1</quantity>
<filename>http://localhost.com/wp-content/uploads/downloads/2010/05/that.zip</filename>
<file_description>Hello developer license</file_description>
<diversion>1.1</diversion>
<hits>0</hits>
<user>myfeed</user>
<members>1</members>

<mirrors>1</mirrors>
</item><item>
<title>Hello Developer 2</title>
<link>http://localhost.com/</link>
<guid>http://localhost.com/</guid>
<pubDate>20100907</pubDate>
<dc:creator>myfeed</dc:creator>
<category><![CDATA[Developer]]></category>
<category><![CDATA[Tutorial]]></category>
<category><![CDATA[Wordpress]]></category>
<description><![CDATA[Hello developer license]]></description>

<license>Developer</license>
<quantity>1</quantity> 
<filename>http://localhost.com/wp-content/uploads/downloads/2010/06/this.zip</filename>
<file_description>Hello developer license</file_description>
<diversion>1.1</diversion>
<hits>0</hits>
<user>myfeed</user>
<members>1</members>
<mirrors>1</mirrors>
</item></channel>
</rss>
```

Comment: Please post full feed contents or at least complete with 1 item.

Comment: What do you mean by 'but failed in google'? Google Chrome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XML is malformed and Firefox displayed it just 'cause it was in a good mood. Pointedly, on line 38 you're closing an `<item>` you haven't opened.